# I was trying to implement useState hook in plain JavaScript to see its working. Below is my code, but it is not working and goes into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems kind of magic to me how React is able to maintain the **state** variable value inside the functional component between re-renders. So I tried to implement myself to see how things work. But fails. If you can point to some good resources where I can see what goes under the hood to achieve this process or can tell what I am doing wrong in the code. React source is a bit hard to understand at this point for me. Thank you.

```js
  const MyReact = {
  state: null,
  stateInitialized: false,
  setState(newState) {
    if (this.state !== newState);
    {
      this.state = newState;
      Component();
    }
  },
  useState(initialValue) {
    if (!this.stateInitialized) {
      this.stateInitialized = true;
      this.state = initialValue;
    }
    return [this.state, this.setState];
  },
};

function Component() {
  const [count, setCount] = MyReact.useState(10);
  console.log(count);
  setCount(20);
}

Component();
```

Comment: `now` or `not`?

Comment: sorry updated. Its not

Comment: Do you want to create a custom hook?

Comment: No, just want to understand how react manages things out of curiosity :)

Comment: Calling the setter function on every render would cause an infinite loop even in real React. Try wrapping your setter call in a function that the user triggers.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your code:

1. Wrong semicolon in `setState()`: `if (this.state !== newState);`, which leads to an unconditional call of `Component()` and thus an endless recursion.
2. More subtle: In `useState()`, you return `this.setState` without binding it to `MyReact`, which leads to `setCount()` setting the `state` globally (i.e. on the `window` object). Replace it with `this.setState.bind(this)`.

Comment: oh, thank you xehpuk, I was stuck in this for more than 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are triggered by events and in turn, dispatch those event changes to the recorded handler (`setCount()`).

The Component is a constructor function and must be instantiated (as seen in line 20 of this [React Source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js)). So this source more closely reflects React's structure.

```js
const MyReact = {
  state: null,
  stateInitialized: false,
  setState(newState) {
    if (this.state !== newState);
    {
      this.state = newState;
    }
    console.log("newCount event calls setState: ",this.state);
  },
  useState(initialValue) {
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    if (!this.stateInitialized) {
      this.stateInitialized = true;
      this.state = initialValue;
    }
    console.log("Component calls useState: ",this.state);
    return [this.state, this.setState];
  },
};

function Component() {
  const [count, setCount] = MyReact.useState(10);
  this.listener = setCount;
}

const component = new Component();

document.addEventListener("newCount", (e) => { component.listener(e.detail.value) });

// create and dispatch the event
var event = new CustomEvent("newCount", {
  detail: {
    value: 0
  }
});

event.detail.value = 20;
document.dispatchEvent(event);
event.detail.value = 30;
document.dispatchEvent(event);
console.log("MyReact.state = ",MyReact.state);
```